# jquery validation regex to match specific format

Tags: regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to match the following format:

`T123ABC`

When people insert they could do it with spaces or dashes. I am trying to use this format for jquery validator but for some reason it is not working:

```
$.validator.addMethod('numberplateTZ', function (value) { 
    var reg = value.replace(" ","");
    reg = reg.replace("-","");
    return /[a-z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-z]{3}$/.test(reg); 
}, 'Numberplate format: T XXX ABC...');
```

Comment: `replace()` with string, replaces a single occurrence, to replace all occurrences use `replace(/\s+/g, '')`. Missing anchor `^` in regex. Use `i` flag for case-insensitive match.

Comment: Sounds like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt9jzbno/)

replace the regex as below

```
return /[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}$/.test(reg);
```